# Django: URL Reverse custom parameter to match?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out if I can build a url which would match objects in my model with other field instead of pk. I have a model which has many fields, and I was happy while using simple `<int:id>` while building url paths, so in this case:

```
path("<int:pk>/", ProductDetailView.as_view(), name="product_detail")
```

But things changed, and we decided to use our old url regex, so instead this we changed to:

```
path("<slug:url>/", ProductDetailView.as_view(), name="product_detail"),
```

Our model have this field:

```
url = models.TextField(null=True)
```

and I can easily filter out by url, like this:
`model.filter(url='/nesiojami-kompiuteriai/nesiojami-kompiuteriai.html')` for example.

I have a problem while trying to reverse and url for the model instance:

```
prod = Product.objects.filter(is_deleted=False, category_id=64, url__isnull=False).first()
return reverse("product:product_detail", kwargs={"url": prod.url})

NoReverseMatch at /nesiojami-kompiuteriai/nesiojami-kompiuteriai/
Reverse for 'product_detail' with keyword arguments '{'url': '/nesiojami-kompiuteriai/nesiojami-kompiuteriai/nesiojamas-kompiuteris-acer-sf314-14-i5-8265-8256gb--9618707.html'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product/(?P<url>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `url` field contains as value:

```
/nesiojami-kompiuteriai/nesiojami-kompiuteriai/nesiojamas-kompiuteris-acer-sf314-14-i5-8265-8256gb--9618707.html
```

This is *not* a slug. A slug is a sequence of alphanumerical characters, hyphens and underscores. But it is not allowed to contain slashes (`/`), or dots (`.`).

If you want to include this, then you can work with a [`<path:…>` path converter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters), which will accept a sequence of characters including the slash and dot:

```
path('<path:url>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_detail'),
```

but perhaps your `url` field contains the wrong data. Typically a slug is made by transforming the title of something into a slug with [**`slugify(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) this will replace all spacing characters with hyphens and remove all characters that are not valid slug characters.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks man!